# Move a file on reboot

Tags: windows-7

I know it's possible but I can't remember how.

I want to move/replace a file on reboot, since it is in use normally. It concerns shell32.dll which I replaced for some visual style. It used to be a hardlink but I lost it's target and I can't replace shell32.dll because it is in use.

In what way would I restore/replace this file? Replacing it on a reboot would work if I knew how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx) for this on Microsoft's great [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) site.

Comment: +1 because I already had this and didn't know about it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I always use [MoveOnBoot](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/MoveOnBoot.shtml), a freeware utility that's easy to use and will do exactly what you want.